# Input does not work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I just started learning programming and I think something is messed up with my code runner in Visual Studio Code. When I try to use input in Python I can not write anything in the terminal. This problem came out recently. It writes that when I try to input anything that it "cannot edit in read-only editor". I also checked in here what could be the solution, but it did not help. Input still does not work. I am on Linux, and I also tried to uninstall the program and code runner as well, none of them worked so far.

Ps: I tried the Code-runner: Run in Terminal box check method, which did not work at all.

Comment: Probably show a few screenshots/video to illustrate the issue, as no one can see your screen.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! As @LexLi stated, it'd be very nice if you could show some screenshots of your issue. If you could annotate them with arrows or alike, it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Link to the screenshot: https://imgur.com/gallery/x0G6zTG 
I really need help.

Comment: If you goto Terminal and say python3 untitled.py it should run.